# Can't use D3D11 Device Debug flags on Windows Server 2019

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio, windows-server-2016, directx, windows-server-2019

I get this error:

```
D3D11CreateDevice: Flags (0x2) were specified which require the D3D11 SDK Layers for Windows 10, but they are not present on the system.
These flags must be removed, or the Windows 10 SDK must be installed.
Flags include: D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG

error: 0x887a002d
```

I've tried:

- Installing Graphics Tools
- Re-installing Windows 10 SDK
- Rebooting after the above

Relevant code:

```
DX_CHECK(D3D11CreateDevice(nullptr, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, nullptr,
                                 creation_flags, feature_levels,
                                 _countof(feature_levels), D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
                                 &device_, &feature_level, &context_));
```

Comment: What version of the Windows 10 SDK?  What is the output of the following command: `Dism /online /add-capability /capabilityname:Tools.Graphics.DirectX~~~~0.0.1.0`?  You do have capatible hardware installed right?

Comment: PS C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> Dism /online /add-capability /capabilityname:Tools.Graphics.DirectX~~~~0.0.1.0

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.17763.1

Image Version: 10.0.17763.379

[==========================100.0%==========================]

Error: 0x80240438

DISM failed. No operation was performed.
For more information, review the log file.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log

Comment: Windows Server 2019 doesn't have the Windows Store so I wonder if it's related.

Comment: The log file will indicate the reason the feature could not be added (which by the way does not appear to be installed).

Comment: This is the error I see: https://gist.github.com/Suhail/beb3ee9e9f25eb24d37d8fc0a74920ff - kinda not clear

Comment: Did you ever get this installed? Same issue  here.